# Using <initializer_list> in C++

Tags: c++, string, class, constructor, initializer-list

I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to use the `<initializer_list>` in C++. Let's pick a simple example:

I've got something like this:

```
using namespace std;

class TV{
    vector<string> channels;
    public:
    TV(initializer_list<string> channels){}
}
```

Let's say this is my main:

```
int main(){
    TV x({"BBC", "CNN"}, y({"SKYNEWS", "FOX", "CNN"});
    return 0;
}
```

How can I create a constructor without default argument-count for strings?

Comment: Something like `TV(initializer_list<string> channels_) : channels(channels_){}`?

Comment: The [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) should help you.  There are a lot of typos you need to fix first.

Comment: You have unbalanced parenthesis for `x`.

Comment: something like x({}), y({})

having multiple variables declared like that on 1 line is bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the constructors of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) directly takes a `std::initializer_list`

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

So you can just initialize in your constructor

```
TV(std::initializer_list<std::string> _channels)
: channels(_channels)
{}
```

Also you should avoid declaring multiple variables on a single line, as your parentheses were mismatched, it would have been more obvious.

```
TV x{{"BBC", "CNN"}};
TV y{{"SKYNEWS", "FOX", "CNN"}};
```

[Working demo](http://ideone.com/opsjgL)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.

There is braces misalignment in `TV x({"BBC", "CNN"}), y({"SKYNEWS", "FOX", "CNN"});` ,while you declared. Adjusted and pasted the code below. It works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class TV{

vector<string> channels;

public:

TV(initializer_list<string> channels1){

    channels = channels1;
}

void printSize()
{

    cout<<channels.size()<<endl;
}


};



int main(){

TV x({"BBC", "CNN"}), y({"SKYNEWS", "FOX", "CNN"});

x.printSize();
y.printSize();

 return 0;
}

The output is 

2
3
```